# Why this program hangs?

Tags: python, sockets

I am pasting whole code, since I think it is as short as it can get;

```
import socket

def recv_all(sock):
    parts = []
    while True:
        msg = ""
        msg = sock.recv(4096)
        print "recieved", len(msg), "bytes."
        if not msg:
            break
        parts.append(msg)
    return "".join(parts)

http_request = """GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: {}
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; tr) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.64
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers


"""
site = "www.google.com.tr"
print "creating connection"
conn = socket.create_connection((site,80))
print "sending data"
conn.sendall(http_request.format(site))
print "recieving response"
response = recv_all(conn)
print "closing connection"
conn.close()

print response
```

When I run this, I get this output;

```
creating connection
sending data
recieving response
recieved 3743 bytes.
recieved 4096 bytes.
recieved 4096 bytes.
recieved 4096 bytes.
recieved 3472 bytes.
recieved 1648 bytes.
```

What I expected it to do is to read 0 bytes after it reads last chunk (1648 in this case). But it keeps waiting instead.

I am on windows 7 with Python 2.7.

What am I doing wrong here? What should I do so that it works as intended?

Comment: Specific answers about keep-alive have been given and they're good, but the big thing you're doing wrong is implementing cargo-cult HTTP instead of reading [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Comment: @AlanCurry Sorry, I am not a native speaker. What does cargo-cult mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming - it means you're trying to reuse a hunk of code (or in this case a big block of HTTP headers) without understanding.

Comment: @AlanCurry I see. I was trying to work with socket module to see what it has to offer. Making a HTTP-request seemed to best way to start. I wasn't trying to implement an actual HTTP-client. Also, I didn't realize reqest headers might effect socket behaviour. Thus, I copied them. I will be more carefull next time.

Comment: This is code review, not a community question.

Comment: @HonestAbe I don't agree. It would have been code review if I didn't mention spesific problem I face. However, I asked about "why this doesn't work", not "How does this code look to you.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sending:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
```

... and the server's doing exactly as you asked - keeping the connection alive at the end. So your read call blocks, waiting for more data - while the server is waiting for another request on the same connection.

*Either* turn off [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), *or* look for a Content-Length header, and stop reading when you've read that much data.

(Alternatively, use an HTTP client library instead of trying to do it yourself :)

Comment: +1 for using an HTTP client library (specifically, look at [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html))

Comment: Sorry for missing that, I copied the request headers from opera, but removing keep-alive doesn't work. I am trying to learn how sockets work, so using HTTP client is not an option for me.

Comment: But, adding "Connection: Close" as @MikkoJuola suggested works.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the HTTP request you send. See this line:

> Connection: Keep-Alive, TE

This tells the server on the other side to keep the connection alive.

Try:

> Connection: Close

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread your question. While this isn't causing your hanging behavior, I think you intend to add the last `msg` to `parts`, which wont happen on the final run because your `if ... break` statement comes before the `.append`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it won't break as long as msg is not empty.